# Что такое базовая линия элемента?

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

По умолчанию label возле textarea принимает значение vertical-align: baseine. То есть label выравнивается относительно базовой линии родительского элемента. В данном случае родительским элементом является fieldset. Где у этого родителя базовая линия? Почему текст прижимается книзу?

Разве базовая линия есть НЕ только у текста?

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

legend {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #f7e8f7;
}

fieldset {
  border: 3px solid purple;
  background: #f7e8f7;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Information</legend>
    <label for="1">Comment here:</label> <textarea name="comment" id="1" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Базовая линия элемента совпадает с базовой линией текста. Где текст располагается - туда и прижимается

Comment: Правда, с textarea ситуация более сложная, у него базовая линия стандартом не определена

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Свойство [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) применимо только к `inline`, `inline-block`, и `table-cell` элементам. Соотвественно "baseline", о котором Вы спрашиваете присутствует только у них.

Оно не применимо к блочным элемента, т.ч таким как `textarea`.

Перечисленные выше элементы будут занимать позицию исходя из своих дефолных настроек (если не задано другого) внутри их родительского элемента.

т.е они встанут там где должны относительно высоты родителя.

Comment: Хорошо, НО если родителем для label является fieldset, почему тогда текст выравнивается относительно textarea?

Comment: @Eva текст выравниваеться относительно свободного места по высоте в родителе (fieldset) а не относительно textarea. В Вашем примере textarea это самый высокий элементы в fieldset, поэтому может создастся ощущение что он выровнен относительно него, но это не так.