# Выравнивание inline-block элемента по вертикали

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, выравнивание

Объясните, пожалуйста, поему так происходит.

В строке есть 2 элемента `<label>` и `<div>`(display: inline-block).

Div имеет высоту `line-height: 32px` и является самым высоким элементом строки.

В какой-то момент у `<div>` появляется свойство `vertical-align: top`. Вопрос в том, почему при появлении этого свойства у `<div>`, `<label>` начинает выравниваться по верхнему краю `<div>`?

В документации написано, что `vertical-align: top` - это выравнивание верхнего края элемента по верху самого высокого элемента строки. В нашем случае, самый высокий элемент является сам `<div>`. И `vertical-align: top` указано исключительно только для него. Почему же в таком случае это влияет на `<label>`?

https://jsfiddle.net/xwurymeg/

```css
    .inline-element {
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 32px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .border-red {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .border-green {
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
        <label class="border-red">text</label>
        <div class="inline-element border-green">
                inline element
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы совершенно верно подметили про высоту самого высокого элемента в блоке, если Вы посмотрите сейчас, то увидите что они выровнены относительно базовой линии (baseline), т.е видно где проходит эта самая линия.
Во варианте с `top`, данный `div` будет выровнен относительно верхней линии:

```css
.inline-element {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.border-red {
  border: 1px solid red; 
}

.border-green {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="border-red">text</label>
  <div class="inline-element border-green">
    inline element
  </div>
</div>
```

Я уже подробно рассматривал этот момент здесь:

[Логика размещения дочерних блоков в HTML/CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1158401/397819)

[Почему label для textarea отображается не сверху, а внизу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1162132/397819)

[Что такое базовая линия элемента?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1162595/397819)

[Почему не работает vertical-align?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1163688/397819)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Если вы откроете Chrome DevTools мой пример и уберете/снова поставите галочку vertical-align: top, то увидите, то не `<div>` выравнивается к базовой лини, а `<label>` скачет туда-сюда. Почему так работает?

Comment: @Pavel именно про это поведение я и говорю, так происходит потому что div это самый высокий элемент из inline-элементов (и вообще из всех, в Вашем примере). А по дефолту у них у обоих baseline (даже если Вы это не прописали).